# tensorflow and keras: None values not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am running the code below in Jupyter notebook. The first chunk of code works okay but when the running the second chunk of code i get an error message "ValueError: None values not supported". I am using tensorflow and keras. Thanks a lot

```
features=skin_df.drop(columns=['cell_type_idx'],axis=1)
target=skin_df['cell_type_idx']

# Train Test Split
x_train_o, x_test_o, y_train_o, y_test_o = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.20,random_state=1234)

x_train = np.asarray(x_train_o['image'].tolist())
x_test = np.asarray(x_test_o['image'].tolist())

x_train_mean = np.mean(x_train)
x_train_std = np.std(x_train)

x_test_mean = np.mean(x_test)
x_test_std = np.std(x_test)

x_train = (x_train - x_train_mean)/x_train_std
x_test = (x_test - x_test_mean)/x_test_std

# Perform one-hot encoding on the labels
y_train = to_categorical(y_train_o, num_classes = 7)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test_o, num_classes = 7)

# Set a learning rate annealer
learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc',
                                            patience=3, 
                                            verbose=1, 
                                            factor=0.5, 
                                            min_lr=0.00001)
```

```
#1. Function to plot model's validation loss and validation accuracy
def plot_model_history(model_history):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))
    # summarize history for accuracy
    axs[0].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['acc'])+1),model_history.history['acc'])
    axs[0].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['val_acc'])+1),model_history.history['val_acc'])
    axs[0].set_title('Model Accuracy')
    axs[0].set_ylabel('Accuracy')
    axs[0].set_xlabel('Epoch')
    axs[0].set_xticks(np.arange(1,len(model_history.history['acc'])+1),len(model_history.history['acc'])/10)
    axs[0].legend(['train', 'val'], loc='best')
    # summarize history for loss
    axs[1].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['loss'])+1),model_history.history['loss'])
    axs[1].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['val_loss'])+1),model_history.history['val_loss'])
    axs[1].set_title('Model Loss')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('Loss')
    axs[1].set_xlabel('Epoch')
    axs[1].set_xticks(np.arange(1,len(model_history.history['loss'])+1),len(model_history.history['loss'])/10)
    axs[1].legend(['train', 'val'], loc='best')
    plt.show()
```

```
epochs = 50 
batch_size = 10
history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train,y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                              epochs = epochs, validation_data = (x_validate,y_validate),
                              verbose = 1, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size
                              , callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction])
```

error message with trace back

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-b36dfc5ecc8e> in <module>
      5                               epochs = epochs, validation_data = (x_validate,y_validate),
      6                               verbose = 1, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size
----> 7                               , callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction])

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1730             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1731             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1732             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1733 
   1734     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
     40 
     41     do_validation = bool(validation_data)
---> 42     model._make_train_function()
     43     if do_validation:
     44         model._make_test_function()

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _make_train_function(self)
    314                     training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
    315                         params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
--> 316                         loss=self.total_loss)
    317                 updates = self.updates + training_updates
    318 

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in symbolic_fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     73         if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
     74             with get_graph().as_default():
---> 75                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     76         else:
     77             return func(*args, **kwargs)

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py in get_updates(self, loss, params)
    541                 self.updates.append(K.update(vhat, vhat_t))
    542             else:
--> 543                 p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(v_t) + self.epsilon)
    544 
    545             self.updates.append(K.update(m, m_t))

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    904         try:
    905           y = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(
--> 906               y, dtype_hint=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
    907         except TypeError:
    908           # If the RHS is not a tensor, it might be a tensor aware object

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1254       name=name,
   1255       preferred_dtype=dtype_hint,
-> 1256       as_ref=False)
   1257 
   1258 

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1312 
   1313     if ret is None:
-> 1314       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1315 
   1316     if ret is NotImplemented:

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    315                                          as_ref=False):
    316   _ = as_ref
--> 317   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    318 
    319 

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    256   """
    257   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 258                         allow_broadcast=True)
    259 
    260 

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    294       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    295           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape,
--> 296           allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    297   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    298   const_tensor = g._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\.conda\envs\Project_2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    437   else:
    438     if values is None:
--> 439       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
    440     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
    441     # provided if possible.

ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Please see the above error code. thanks

Comment: Please post the full error message with traceback.

Comment: Full error message is added to the code now. thanks

Comment: I think we need to see the lines where you define all the parameters you pass to `model.fit_generator` (`x_train` ... `learning_rate_reduction`). One of them seems to be `None` for some reason.

Comment: Code has been updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by creating a new environment and installing Keras and not tensorflow that seems to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think in model.compile you have assigned optimizer with predefined variable instead of that use this one """model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam' I wish the best

Comment: Welcome to Stack community. Thank you for the answer. Buy your answer should be edited, I suggest you to take a look for SO tutorial for how to post an answer.